# Load more meshes in the same assetsmanager task Babylon JS

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

is it possibile to load more meshes in the same task?
For example, using this code:

```
    var modelTask = assetsManager.addMeshTask("model", "", "public/Models/", "model1.stl");
    modelTask = assetsManager.addMeshTask("model", "", "public/Models/", "model2.stl");

    modelTask.onSuccess = function (task) {
        var p = task.loadedMeshes.length;

    }
```

the loadedMeshes only has lenght equal to 1...so there is only a mesh in that array.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have to have a onSuccess per meshTask (here you are overwriting the variable)